# Unity UI image doesn't change color although Selectable disabled

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I am instantiating a UI image prefab in Unity and sets its color, but it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
public class Test
{
    public ImageInitializer pImage;

    private void Start()
    {
        var temp = Instantiate(pImage, GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Canvas>().transform);
        temp.Selectable = false;
        temp.Color = Color.red;
    }
}

public class ImageInitializer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image image;
    public Selectable selectable;

    public bool Selectable
    {
        set => selectable.enabled = value;
    }

    public Color Color
    {
        set => image.color = value;
    }
}
```

And the prefab is just a simple UI button with the ImageInitializer script on it.

But it doesn't set the color. in fact, the image component's color is set, but it is still using the selectable's normal color. If I turn it on and off in the editor everything is working.

Do you know why it doesn't update the image¿

===**EDIT**===

So far I tried `LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate(temp.transform as RectTransform)` and `temp.image.SetAllDirty()` and a coroutine that disables the `Selectable`, wait one frame and sets the color.

Nothing worked...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make a custom image class which is selectable, make a custom class which has an image you can manipulate which is also a child of 'Selectable'. Right now you have a random selectable not attached to anything/doing anything. You can make the code your own but something like this:

```
public class ImageInitializer : Selectable
    {
    public Image image;

    //use enabled = true or enabled = false;

    public Color Color
    {
        set => image.color = value;
    }
}
```

Then you can implement methods like 'OnPointerEnter' 'OnPointerExit' 'OnPointerDown'... etc

Comment: The prefab is also used in other parts of the project, so I need the selectable component. The weird part is that my code is fine if the selectable is turned off in the prefab (but I can't turn it off because, again, I use it in other places)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of unity editor are u using ?

I guess its just an issue with not rebuilding .

```
public ImageInitializer pImage;
private void Start()
{
    var temp = Instantiate(pImage, GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Canvas>().transform);
    temp.Selectable = false;
    temp.Color = Color.red;
    LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate(temp.GetComponent<RectTransform>());
}
```

Comment: I am using Unity 2018.3.14f1, and unfortunately this solution didn't work. The image color is still isn't updated